# Add a prefix to WooCommerce product titles based on categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

Is there any chance to have a prefix title for specific categories of woocommerce products?

**For example:**

If I add an RTX 2080Ti to GPU Category the title needs to be [GPU] RTX 2080Ti.

---

I have tried many codes around the internet but couldn't reach my target.

```php
add_filter('wp_title', 'WPSE_20181106_prepend_title', 10, 3);
function WPSE_20181106_prepend_title($title, $sep, $seplocation) {
    // not a single post
    if (!is_singular('post')) {
        return $title;
    }

    // IDs of categories that should prepend the title
    $prepend_categories = [15, 35];

    // get all categories of post
    $categories = get_the_category();
    foreach ($categories as $category) {
        // found category
        if (in_array($category->term_id, $prepend_categories)) {
            // return new format, using __() so it is translateable
            return sprintf('%s %s: %s',
                __('Download', 'lang-slug'),
                $category->name,
                $title
            );
        }
    }
    // category not found, return default
    return $title;
}
```

Can someone guide to make this function work for woocommerce?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> You can use several [Conditional Tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/), depending on where you would like to change the product title.
>
> With the code below the adjustment are done on the single product page

```php
function change_title ( $title, $post_id ) {
    // Returns true on a single product page.
    if ( is_product() ) {
        // IDs of categories that should prepend the title
        $prepend_categories = array( 15, 16 );

        // get all categories via post id
        $categories = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'product_cat' ); 

        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {          
            // Find category
            if ( in_array( $category->term_id, $prepend_categories ) ) {
                $title = '[' . $category->name . ']' . $title;
            }
        }
    }

    return $title;
} 
add_filter('the_title', 'change_title', 10, 2 );
```