# How to add a CSS class for the displayed discounted percentage near sale price on single product pages in WooCommerce

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, discount

I using "[Display the discounted percentage near sale price in Single product pages for WC 3.0+](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43771188/11987538)" (Original answer code)

I used this code to show sale percentage after price on single product page. but I want to customize it - to give it background, paddings, etc...

So I need to include CSS class name in that function to be able to customize it via CSS

I want to add it only to "`-percentage`" (I don't want it to be applied neither to discounted or regular price)

Comment: Do you mean?  `<del class="myclass">`. 
Your question is not entirely clear to me, can you adjust it with more details?

Comment: I used this code to show sale percentage after price on single product page. but I want to customize it - to give it background, paddings and etc. So I need to include CSS class name in that function("myclass") to be able to customize it via css

Comment: yes, you already mentioned that in your question. I asked for more and clearer details. 
The function provides a certain output, on which element do you want to add the class?  Can I assume that what I just mentioned as an example has solved your question?

Comment: I want it to apply both "-" and price, not only price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some additional information

- HTML [`<del>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_del.asp) Tag
- HTML [`<ins>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ins.asp) Tag
- How TO - [Add a Class](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_add_class.asp)

So you get

```php
function woocommerce_custom_sales_price( $price, $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
    $percentage = round( ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) / $regular_price * 100 ).'%';
    $percentage_txt = '<span class="my-class">' . __('-', 'woocommerce' ) . $percentage . '</span>';
    $price = '<del>' . ( is_numeric( $regular_price ) ? wc_price( $regular_price ) : $regular_price ) . '</del>
    <ins>' . ( is_numeric( $sale_price ) ? wc_price( $sale_price ) . $percentage_txt : $sale_price . $percentage_txt ) . '</ins>';

    return $price;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'woocommerce_custom_sales_price', 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Hi again, Sorry for bothering... I want this function to be applied only on single product page.(now it applies to shop page too) how to do that?

Comment: Add a if statement with a [Conditional Tag](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) - `is_product()`
Returns true on a single product page. See how this is applied in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61753313/11987538)

Comment: Hi :) I encountered problem with variable product. If product is variable it shows NAN% do you know how to solve it? Thannk you

Comment: I just retested this code, this code still works for both single and variable products without any problems. I think the problem is elsewhere, you will have to debug in your own setup to fix the problem